# Calculate original data forecast interval from differenced data forecast interval

Tags: forecasting, references, data-transformation, arima, prediction-interval

How to calculate original data forecast interval from differenced data forecast interval?

Please provide formulas or bibliographic reference.

Comment: Sounds like a question to me, also pretty polite (includes a *please*). And I wonder, why exactly do some people think this is off topic?

Answer (score 1):

Say the level at some time $t$ is written as $Y_{t}$. If the difference is written as $D_{t+1} = Y_{t+1} - Y_t$, then $Y_{t+1} |y_{1:t} = D_{t+1}+y_{t} |y_{1:t}$. So the random level is just the random difference plus your last observed non-random level. You just shift it by a constant. The mean will change, the variance will not, and you may or may not have the same type of random variable after you shift it.

Example: say you your forecast distribution for the difference is $p(d_{t+1}|y_{1:t}) = p(d_{t+1}|d_{1:t}) = \text{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then $p(y_{t+1}|y_{1:t}) = \text{Normal}(\mu + y_{t}, \sigma^2).$ This is because the Normal family of random variables is closed under constant shifts.